# Iterate over two hashMap and compare the keys and compare the elements that form the key to populate final hashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

```
Class OpsRecord{
 private String id;
 private long sequenceNumber;

 //implemented hashcode and equals method considering both id and version.
 //So two OpsRecord are equal only if two OpsRecord has same id and sequenceNumber.
}

Class OpsCompleteRecord{
 // This class has 20 class variables including id and sequenceNumber.
}
```

I have an existing `Map` that has the following values. Assuming the values are coming from a random data source.

```
Map<OpsRecord, OpsCompleteRecord> sourceMap = new HashMap<>();



sourceMap.put(new OpsRecord("1","1"), new OpsCompleteRecord());
        sourceMap.put(new OpsRecord("1","3"), new OpsCompleteRecord());
        sourceMap.put(new OpsRecord("1","2"), new OpsCompleteRecord());
        sourceMap.put(new OpsRecord("2","2"), new OpsCompleteRecord());
        sourceMap.put(new OpsRecord("2","1"), new OpsCompleteRecord());
```

I want a target map that should contain only `OpsCompleteRecord` whose `id` is 1 and `sequenceNumber` is 3 , and another one with `id`=2 and `sequenceNumber`=2.
[Latest `sequenceNumber` for a `id`]

targetMap

```
new OpsRecord("1","3"), new OpsCompleteRecord()
new OpsRecord("2","2"), new OpsCompleteRecord()
```

I am trying to implement with the below logic and code. Need your help in populating targetMap.
I think I am messing up with the logic.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<OpsRecord, OpsCompleteRecord> sourceMap = new HashMap<>();

        sourceMap.put(new OpsRecord("1","1"), new OpsCompleteRecord());
        sourceMap.put(new OpsRecord("1","3"), new OpsCompleteRecord());
        sourceMap.put(new OpsRecord("1","2"), new OpsCompleteRecord());
        sourceMap.put(new OpsRecord("2","2"), new OpsCompleteRecord());
        sourceMap.put(new OpsRecord("2","1"), new OpsCompleteRecord());

        // Populate the target map 
        Map<OpsRecord, OpsCompleteRecord> targetMap = new HashMap<>();

        Iterator<OpsRecord> itr = sourceMap.keySet().iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext()){
            OpsRecord opsRecord = itr.next();
            // Iterate over targetMap.keySet(). 
            //     Take each key.getId()
            //     Compare targetMap key.getId() with opsRecord.getId() 
            //         and if equal then Compare targetMap key.getSequenceNumber() with opsRecord.getSequenceNumber()
             //                          if getSequenceNumber is small in targetMap, overwrite the object else ignore.
             //            else if all key.getId() is not equal to opsRecord.getId() then add that key and value to targetMap           
        }       

    }
```

I am using Java7.

Answer (score 2):

In **Java7**, maybe you can try to use [guava](https://github.com/google/guava) `Maps.filterKeys`, like:

```
    Map<OpsRecord, OpsCompleteRecord> sourceMap = new HashMap();

    sourceMap.put(new OpsRecord("1", 1), new OpsCompleteRecord());
    sourceMap.put(new OpsRecord("1", 3), new OpsCompleteRecord());
    sourceMap.put(new OpsRecord("1", 2), new OpsCompleteRecord());
    sourceMap.put(new OpsRecord("2", 2), new OpsCompleteRecord());
    sourceMap.put(new OpsRecord("2", 1), new OpsCompleteRecord());
    Map<OpsRecord, OpsCompleteRecord> targetMap = Maps.filterKeys(sourceMap, new Predicate<OpsRecord>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(OpsRecord input) {
            return input.id.equals(Long.toString(input.sequenceNumber));
        }
    });
```

In **Java8**, you can use `stream` with `filter` and `collector` can easy to do this:

```
    sourceMap.put(new OpsRecord("1", 1), new OpsCompleteRecord());
    sourceMap.put(new OpsRecord("1", 3), new OpsCompleteRecord());
    sourceMap.put(new OpsRecord("1", 2), new OpsCompleteRecord());
    sourceMap.put(new OpsRecord("2", 2), new OpsCompleteRecord());
    sourceMap.put(new OpsRecord("2", 1), new OpsCompleteRecord());
    Map<OpsRecord, OpsCompleteRecord> targetmap =
            sourceMap.entrySet().stream()
                    .filter(i -> i.getKey().id.equals(Long.toString(i.getKey().sequenceNumber)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

another thing need to call out: `sequenceNumber` is `long` type, so it should use `new OpsRecord("2", 1)`.

Hopefully, it's helpful.

Comment: Thanks but  I am using Java 7 , my bad let me update tag

Comment: Thank you, this was useful +1 . sorry for late response. However this one compare the `id` and `sequenceNumber` and checks if they are equal. It doesn't give the expected output. Also it doesn't compare with the `targetMap` to check if it already has the `id`. But this gives an idea. How to compare with the `targetMap` inside the `apply()` is something I need to figure out. Anyways I found a diff approach which I will post here separately.